# How is this struct referenced? And what are the colons (:) at the bottom?

Tags: c++, struct, reference, static

```
static struct {
    uint16_t foo;
    uint16_t bar;
    uint16_t foo1;
    uint16_t bar1;
} foo_bar = {
    foo  : 1500,
    bar  : 1500,
    foo1 : 1500,
    bar1 : 1500
};
```

What i am wondering is what the equals sign is used for at the bottom, and why there is a colon and then a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This form of initialization appears to be a GNU extension. `clang++` tells me:

```
quirk.cpp:10:5: warning: use of GNU old-style field designator extension [-Wgnu-designator]
```

The standard (at least in C99, not in C++) equivalent of this is the `.field = <expr>` syntax:

```
static struct {
    uint16_t foo;
    uint16_t trim2;
    uint16_t foo1;
    uint16_t bar1;
} elevon = {
    .foo = 1500,
    .trim2 = 1500,
    .foo1 = 1500,
    .bar1 = 1500
};
```

So, all this code does is declaring and initializing the variable `elevon` of which the type is an anonymous struct, and initializing it (its members) with values.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to run it in Visual C++ but it threw an error. Apparently arduino uses an old struct format.

Comment: @user2486796 I don't think it's the Arduino library that is faulty. Visual C++ doesn't respect practically *any* standard, I wouldn't be surprised if the C compiler implemented this badly.